# Matlab: removing rows when there are repeated values in columns

Tags: performance, matlab

I have a problem with removing the rows when the columns are identical.

I have used a for and if loop but the run time is too long.

I was thinking if there are any more efficient and faster run time method.
say

`A=[ 2 4 6 8;
      3 9 7 9;
      4 8 7 6;
      8 5 4 6;
      2 10 11 2]`

I would want the result to be

```
A=[ 2 4 6 8;
    4 8 7 6;
    8 5 4 6]
```

eliminating the 2nd row because of the repeated '9' and remove the 5th row because of repeated '2'.

Comment: Your original matrix is A(5X4). Subtract 1st column from other 3 columns. Remove those rows with an element = 0. Subtract 2nd column (in new matrix) from the 2 columns to the right. Remove those rows with an element = 0. Subtract 3rd column from the 1 column to the right. Remove rows again. Now add 1st column in resulting matrix to all other columns. Add 2nd column to those to the right. Continue to get back required matrix.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sort` and `diff` to identify the rows with repeated values

```
A = A(all(diff(sort(A'))),:)
```

returns

```
A =
     2     4     6     8
     4     8     7     6
     8     5     4     6
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is how to find the rows with repeated values in an efficient manner.
How about this:

```
% compare all-vs-all for each row using `bsxfun`
>> c = bsxfun( @eq, A, permute( A, [1 3 2] ) );
>> c = sum( c, 3 ); % count the number of matches each element has in the row
>> c = any( c > 1, 2 ); % indicates rows with repeated values - an element with more than one match
>> A = A( ~c, : )
 A =
  2     4     6     8
  4     8     7     6
  8     5     4     6
```

Comment: hey, thanks for your reply, this method does cut down on the run time.

Comment: @user2573873 welcome to stackoverflow. If you found this answer useful, please consider "accepting" it by clicking the "V" icon beside it.